# Json file updates but bot reads the old file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

So I've made a command that simply adds or removes IDs from a JSON file. This JSON is just a small database for whitelisted users.

The command works perfectly fine and the JSON file gets updated, but every time the command gets called to edit it again, it doesn't read the new version, instead, it reads the old unedited one.

So I'm guessing I'll somehow need to update it for the bot but I don't know how I would go on about that.

Anyone know how or why this is happening and have a solution? Here's the command code:

```js
else if (command === 'whitelist') {
    const user = msg.mentions.users.first();
    if (!user) return msg.reply('Please mention a user!')
    const tester = require('./whitelist.json')
    const test = Object.values(tester.newdata).find(object => object.ID === msg.author.id)
    if (!test) return msg.reply("Sorry you can't use this!");
    if (test) {
        const json = require('./whitelist.json')
        const item = Object.values(json.newdata).find(object => object.ID === user.id)
        if (item) {
            msg.reply("Remove mentioned user from whitelist?")
            msg.react('').then(r => {
                msg.react('');
            });
            msg.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == msg.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '' || reaction.emoji.name == ''), {
                max: 1,
                time: 30000
            }).then(collected => {
                if (collected.first().emoji.name == '') {
                    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./whitelist.json');
                    let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
                    delete data.newdata[user]
                    fs.writeFileSync("./whitelist.json", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), (err) => {
                        if (err)
                            embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                            .setTitle('Error report')
                            .addField(`Logged error:`, err, false)
                            .addField(`Server:`, `${msg.guild}`, false)
                            .addField(`Command:`, `${command} ${commandArgs}`, false)
                            .setColor('#0099ff');
                        webhookClient.send(embed)
                    })
                    msg.reply("Removed user!")
                } else
                    msg.reply('Operation canceled.');
            }).catch(() => {
                msg.reply('No reaction after 30 seconds, operation canceled');
            });
            return
        }
        if (!item) {
            let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./whitelist.json');
            msg.reply("Add mentioned user to whitelist?")
            msg.react('').then(r => {
                msg.react('');
            });
            msg.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == msg.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '' || reaction.emoji.name == ''), {
                max: 1,
                time: 30000
            }).then(collected => {
                if (collected.first().emoji.name == '') {
                    let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
                    data.newdata[user] = {
                        "ID": user.id
                    }
                    fs.writeFileSync("./whitelist.json", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), (err) => {
                        if (err)
                            embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                            .setTitle('Error report')
                            .addField(`Logged error:`, err, false)
                            .addField(`Server:`, `${msg.guild}`, false)
                            .addField(`Command:`, `${command} ${commandArgs}`, false)
                            .setColor('#0099ff');
                        webhookClient.send(embed)
                    })
                    msg.reply("Whitelisted user!")
                } else
                    msg.reply('Operation canceled.');
            }).catch(() => {
                msg.reply('No reaction after 30 seconds, operation canceled');
            });
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have a way to improve my code id be happy to hear it

Comment: You should indent your code

Comment: well for u that might work but i prefer if its all lined up 
dont kill me o.o

Comment: Do you really prefer this "indentation"?

Comment: i mean yeah i do lmao

Comment: Not only is it standard to indent your code, but you'll soon notice it makes your code much easier to read and handle down the line.

Comment: ive done all my coding like this and i have no issues with it. i guess it more a personal preference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this but just not using Json's activly and looking back that was a dumb choice
simply use Json's to save every like hour and/or when u shut ur bot down that way u still save data but dont overuse the files. Small example:

```
const UseThisToEdit = [];

//start up
client.once('ready', async () => {
    let FileData = fs.readFileSync('./MyJsonFile.json');
    let Data = JSON.parse(FileData );
    UseThisToEdit = Data 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with JSon, but if the file is updated then how can the bot read the earlier version?

Try all your commits, saves, flush, etc. It's the only way to ensure the changes or updates aren't rolled back. Check for conflicts with any caching as well.

Comment: i dont know how either it does work fine when the bot is restarted. so it can edit the file but can only read the edits after a resart

Comment: There seems to be a couple of conditions in your code. Create a test where you perform one simple write and read. If the bot works fine then, you'll know the issue is with your conditions.

Comment: meh i use the json only for when the bot goes down now ty for trying to help doe

Answer (score 0):

Alright so i solved my issue by just adding a variable inside my code and updating that toghether with the Json so when the bot restarts it gets the data from the Json into the variable and i can work off that

```js
var wl = [];



client.once('ready', async () => {
client.user.setActivity('Starting up ...')
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./whitelist.json');
let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
wl = data
console.log('Conected!')
console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});



else if (command === 'whitelist') { 
const user = msg.mentions.users.first();
if (!user) return msg.reply('Please mention a user!');
if (user.id === msg.author.id) return msg.reply("I'm questioning why you're trying to remove your own permissions?");
if (user.id === "361511417800556546") return msg.reply("Sorry buddy that user is untouchable!")
const test = Object.values(wl.newdata).find(object => object.ID === msg.author.id)
if(!test)return msg.reply("Sorry you can't use this!");
if(test){
const item = Object.values(wl.newdata).find(object => object.ID === user.id)
if (item){
msg.reply("Remove mentioned user from whitelist?")
msg.react('').then(r => {
msg.react('');});
msg.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == msg.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '' || reaction.emoji.name == ''),
{ max: 1, time: 30000 }).then(collected => {if (collected.first().emoji.name == '') {
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./whitelist.json');
let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
delete data.newdata [user]
fs.writeFileSync("./whitelist.json", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), (err) => { if (err) 
embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle('Error report')
.addField(`Logged error:`, err, false)
.addField(`Server:`, `${msg.guild}`, false)
.addField(`Command:`, `${command} ${commandArgs}`, false)
.setColor('#0099ff');
webhookClient.send(embed)
})
wl = data;
msg.reply("Removed user!")}
else
msg.reply('Operation canceled.');
}).catch(() => {msg.reply('No reaction after 30 seconds, operation canceled');});
return
}
if (!item){ 
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./whitelist.json');
msg.reply("Add mentioned user to whitelist?")
msg.react('').then(r => {
msg.react('');});
msg.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == msg.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '' || reaction.emoji.name == ''),
{ max: 1, time: 30000 }).then(collected => {if (collected.first().emoji.name == '') {
let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
data.newdata [user] = {"ID": user.id}
fs.writeFileSync("./whitelist.json", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), (err) => {
if (err) 
embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle('Error report')
.addField(`Logged error:`, err, false)
.addField(`Server:`, `${msg.guild}`, false)
.addField(`Command:`, `${command} ${commandArgs}`, false)
.setColor('#0099ff');
webhookClient.send(embed)
})
wl = data;
msg.reply("Whitelisted user!")}
else
msg.reply('Operation canceled.');
}).catch(() => {msg.reply('No reaction after 30 seconds, operation canceled');});
return}}
}
```